# How to copy the text on the button into the EditText

Tags: android

I have an EditText. Then I make a layout xml with four buttons called button.xml. When the user click, I load the button.xml. Then when the user click one of the buttons, the text on the button will be copied into the EditText. My question is how to copy the text on the button into the EditText?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String text= yourbutton.getText().toString();
youredittext.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following inside your desired event/function that you want to perform this action for you.

```
    Button btnTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    EditText myTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditBox);

    myTextBox.setText(btnTest.getText().toString());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First copy the text of the Button to a String Using the code

String btntext= BUTTON_ID.getText().toString();

Then paste the contents of the Edit Text using

EDITTEXTID.setText(text);

Answer (score 0):

```
Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
EditText ed= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
ed.setText(b.getText().toString());// get text futtonrom button and set text
```